# Adding epublib to Android Studio and run it

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, epub, epublib

I've got a problem with libaries with Android Studio.
I added the .jar in the libs folder in my project and clicked RMB to add it as libary.
In the build.gradle I added this with the dependencies:

```
compile files('libs/epublib-core-latest.jar')
```

This is working but when I'm running the application I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find class 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader', referenced from method com.MJV.Reader.MainActivity.onCreate
```

And this is the code which could be causing it:

```
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println("hoi");
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
                .open("books/testbook.epub");
        Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
        System.out.println("Hier komt het...");
        System.out.println(book.getTitle());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} ...
```

I think the libary isn't included when the application is send to my phone, but I could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
The build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

}
    apply plugin: 'android'

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
```

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
```

}

```
dependencies {

// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
// The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
// compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
compile files('libs/epublib-core-latest.jar')
```

}

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to include in your project the binary for [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/android/)
 slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar which is a dependency for epublib.

After pasting it in your libs folder together with epublib make sure you mention it also in your graddle script.

This line taken from Android Studio is very handy since compiles all the *.jar files in the libs folder:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```